# Export table from Azure & Backup DB locally

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure and I have a few doubts I'm having trouble with.

I purchased a DB for which I pay just a few bucks a month for testing purposes. I was able to replicate and connect to the DB just fine.

My problem comes in two scenarios

1. I cannot find a way, at the SQL Server Management Studio, to back up the DB to my VPS (also at Azure).
2. Is there a way to create a script to duplicate the database tables and indexes structure in order to copy that database to another machine?

Comment: I won't lie, I'm pretty sure this is the 4th time this week I'm made this comment; people setting up Azure SQL Databases most be popular this week. 1. You don't use the traditional backups and restores on Azure SQL Databases, you would use BACPACs and DACPACs.

Comment: 2. Use the Generate Script tool in SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

A data-tier application (DAC) is a logical database management entity that describes all SQL Server objects connected with a user's database, such as tables, views, and instance objects, including logins. A DAC package, also known as a DACPAC, is a self-contained unit of SQL Server database deployment that allows data-tier developers and database administrators to package SQL Server objects into a portable artefact called a DAC package.

A BACPAC is a similar artefact that contains both the database schema and the data contained in it.

> Using [sqlpackage.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) may be run from the command line. There
> appear to be two options:
>
> To include data in the extraction, use the ExtractAllTableData option
> to extract a DACPAC and then publish it to Azure.
>
> After exporting a BACPAC, import it into Azure.

To more about the operations could be performed using BAPAC and DACPAC, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/data-tier-applications?view=sql-server-ver15#dac-operations) the MSFT Document.